# jquery inputmask - how to enforce upper case entries

Tags: jquery, input-mask

The British Post Code contains upper case letters and integers.
When a user enters in a postcode, all the letters should automatically be upper case.
One way to enforce this is to use the JQuery input mask.
However I am struggling to get the syntax right.

```
$(".maskToUpper").inputmask("AAAAAAAAAA", { autoCasing: "upper" });
```

I get the error message

```
Unhandled exception at line 46, column 13 in http://localhost:60858/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js

0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.masktoupper').inputmask({
    mask: ["AAAAAAAAAA", "X"],
    definitions: {
        "X": { casing: "upper" }
    }
})
```

Comment: I still get Unhandled exception at line 50, column 40 in http://localhost:60858/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js

0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action